# How to resolve missing androidx components in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, androidx

Android Studio 3.6.3 on Mac OS 10.14.6 Mojave keeps insisting that it can't resolve parts of androidx in a .java file, like so:

[image]

The build.gradle file looks like this:

```
group 'com.somedev.someplugin'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
}
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the entire Flutter/Android toolchain with the latest stable versions available. Maybe I've overlooked an important library path or SDK setting?

In case it matters: I'm coming from iOS and new to Android Studio and I'm trying to write a Flutter plugin with native code for iOS + Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the upper right corner of the editor, it says "Open for Editing in Android Studio"

Click there and you are good to go!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working! Why would Android Studio offer me to "Open for Editing in Android Studio" if I'm already viewing the file in Android Studio? It seems that by doing so, the Project navigator panel on the left changed scope into the Android project of the Flutter plugin package. I must be opening the project in the wrong way then?

Comment: Sure, another option would be to change the scope of Android studio by clicking the drop-down in top of your project files. If you look at there you will see it says project, if you click it lets you choose Android. It should have the same effect. Let me know if this second option works for you!